# .innerHtml text updates during script execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, innerhtml

I am confused as to why I cannot get text updates during a javascript/jquery/ajax execution.

I have the following code.

```
$("#updates").html("Collecting your team names.");
YourTeamFirst(YourTeam, TeamValue);

$("#updates").html("Collecting their team names.");
TheirTeamNext(TheirTeam, TeamValue);

$("#updates").html("Gathering ID's.");
setNames(TeamValue);

$("#updates").html("Setting Details.");
setChampRatios(TeamValue);

$("#updates").html("Setting Ratios.");
setChampKDRS(TeamValue);

$("#updates").html("Finished!");
```

i.e.

Example function (the only ajax that occurs is in the sub-functions, the actual function calls and text updates are in a plain JS function, no ajax on that...)

```
function TheirTeamNext(TheirTeam, TeamValue) {
      $.ajax({
          url: "/PlayerLookUp/TheirRankedData",
          type: "POST",
          data: "IDList=" + T[i],
          dataType: "json",
          async: false,
          success: function (resp) {
                   //just boring logic
          },
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 0) {
                        alert("Issue with reaching Riot API server. Pleast contact an Admin.");
               }
          }
      });       
}
```

And the only thing that ever appears is "Finished" (after the script is done), why won't anything else appear at all? The execution takes about 10 seconds so other updates should be popping up in the innerHtml/Html. I have also tried using `document.getElementById("updates").innerHTML = ...`, which also shows nothing then when its done will show the "Finished" text.

Each function is either JQuery, Ajax, or javascript with a few back and forth's from my C# controller, but I feel like the text updates should still be updating my innerHtml text unless there  is some script thing I am unaware of for innerHtml/Html...

ALSO: If I toss in an `alert()` somewhere, the most previous text update will appear. So how come only an alert interruption or end of script execution will update/post my text. I would like my users to see updated messages on going with the script.

Comment: Please post a complete code example so we can see everything that you're doing. Odds are though that all your .html() statements are being executed, but too quickly to see anything but the last update. Again, without code it's card to say, but since you said the alert works and alert is blocking, that's my guess.

Comment: @j08691 If the issue is like "propagation" this is taking about 10 seconds right now for sure, as I do 3rd party API calls which alone take 1-2 seconds each and I am doing about 20 so far.

Comment: You should force an UI redraw before blocking the browser's UI, meaning between the `html()` method call and the sync ajax ones. That's said, its quite unclear question imho

Comment: So could you try: `$("#updates").html("Collecting your team names.").prop('offsetHeight');
YourTeamFirst(YourTeam, TeamValue);` and so on for each ones?  Or better, why don't you use asynchronous ajax requests instead???

Comment: @A.Wolff I tried that but it didn't seem to work. If you go here: http://pastebin.com/GDXaymAb I posted it. It's the second function done, called verifyNames (Oh and its not inside the playerViews thing, FYI)

Comment: And what about using asynchronous ajax requests instead?

Comment: @A.Wolff I cannot do that as the API site (which I get data from) process everything asynchronously, so if I have both ends going async, then I can't keep track of multiple things at once unless I want to re-sort every step of the way. So I force my side to go non-async so that I can easily track and keep my data sets together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because ajax is executed ansynchronous.

if you want text like that to appear, you need to use callbacks in your ajax functions.

**update:** since you are using `async: false` this behaviour seems really strange, but I don't know how javascript and jquery exactly handle `synchronous` calls in your case.

one hotfix-suggestion would be to still add callbacks to your functions. (**note**: *this is a very messy workaround and should just help you hotfixing your problem.*)

```
function YourTeamFirst(YourTeam, TeamValue, callback) {
    /* ... */
    $.ajax({
        /* ... */
        success: function (resp) {
            /* ... */
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

then in your function calls add anonymous functions as callback-parameter. in the body of these functions always add the `.html()` for the next function to be executed.

```
$("#updates").html("Collecting your team names.");

YourTeamFirst(YourTeam, TeamValue, function () {
    $("#updates").html("Collecting their team names.");
});

TheirTeamNext(TheirTeam, TeamValue, function () {
    $("#updates").html("Gathering ID's.");
});
/* ... */
```

Comment: I have all my ajax functions set to async: false. And these statements are outside of ajax, ajax would only occur inside of the functions that appear next to my text ones shown above, such inside the function of `setNames(TeamValue);` (or does that not matter?).

Comment: @Austin `I have all my ajax functions set to async: false` Why don't you put this statement in question itself???

Comment: @Austin well without seeing more of your code, i can't say more about it.

Comment: @A.Wolff Because my text updates are not inside of an Ajax function, its inside of a normal javascript function, does that matter?

Comment: @Austin it does matter with async ajax, because the function being called is considered finished once you are getting to the ajax-call inside of it.

Comment: So if my function has function calls inside of it, then that parent function is considered ajax too? Sorry if I am mis-reading, trying to understand haha

Comment: @Austin it may seem confusing, but it's easier than it seems. the browser continues executing your code after the ajax-call is made. it doesn't wait for your ajax-call to succeed. but this should not be the case if you are using `async: false` (which you shouldn't anyways).

Comment: I posted a pastebin above in the thread comments as well. But I have to have to turn async off otherwise my API requests, and the return information will both be async'ed and my data gets all jumbled together :/ If i were to console.log the updates it works just fine, which is why I figured a visual update shouldn't be any different...

Comment: @Austin that's some wall of code. if you could reduce it to the max, this would be a win - win situation: helping yourself to debug the code, and helping us to see problems in it.

Comment: Super reduction visual: http://i.imgur.com/QaTNCwc.png?1 I plan on making this all more dynamic (crunching all the code to recursion) but is static right now for learning purposes on API requests. I am still unsure why my text will not update when ajax's async is off. Remember, that main function is not inside ajax at all, only its function calls (that are next to the text updates) contain any sort of Ajax, which is turned off for async. If I do `console.log` updates, it works just fine too..

Comment: @Austin where exactly are you using `console.log` ? and since you are talking about some API, are you doing cross-domain-requests with your ajax?

Comment: @northkildonan originally instead of the text updates (.html/innerhtml) I just did console.log("my messages") where the updates are at, and they would slowly pop up as the script went on. I figured my .innherhtml/.html would do the same. Yes, I send requests to my controller (C#) which does the request with my keys, then passes my json data back to the javascript for dissection.

Comment: @Austin your ajax itself is not cross-domain then. but that your `console.log` messages work the right way is reall strange. will update my answer with a suggestion to solve your problem in a sec.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66159/discussion-between-austin-and-northkildonan). <- I can show you a demo?